# Daloradius / Freeradius mac authentication

Tags: authentication, port, mac, radius

I setup a centos freeradius mysql with the frontend daloradius using the steps on this site http://linuxdrops.com/install-freeradius-with-web-based-management-daloradius-on-centosrhel-debian-ubuntu/

The installation seems ok i tried telneting and passing username/password on the switch.

The question is will this be enough for mac authentication port based on cisco switch. (just by adding mac address on daloradius new user page mac address authentication.

(I'm a newbie on radius)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using daloradius as front end on radius is ok as per my testing. Also you need to configure the cisco switch to accept the query from the radius server. The logs on the cisco switch will tell if you are connected or not. Verified working for mac based authentication.